# Wait for multiple promises to finish

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, ionic2

I am using the SQLStorage from the Ionic platform. The `remove` function returns a promise. In my code I need to remove multiple values. When these are all finished I need to execute some code.

How can I wait for all of these and then execute a callback function?

**Code:**

```
removeAll() {    
  this.storage.remove(key1);
  this.storage.remove(key2);
  this.storage.remove(key3);    
}
```

Nesting all is a bad practise so I am looking for a decent solution :)

```
removeAll() {
  return this.storage.remove(key1).then(() => {
    this.storage.remove(key2).then(() => {
      this.storage.remove(key3);        
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can use

```
removeAll() {
  Promise.all([
    this.storage.remove(key1),
    this.storage.remove(key2),
    this.storage.remove(key3),
  ]).then(value => doSomething());
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: I would add that if any of these promises rejects, `Promise.all` will immediately reject (whether or not the rest have finished) and the `then` will be skipped. If you need to run `doSomething()` whether they succeed or they fail, you need to `catch` each of then individually to return a `Promise.resolve()`.

Comment: With `Promise.all()`, will they be excecuted one after each other, or all at once ?

Comment: All calls are executed immediately, then `Promise.all()` just waits for all these promises to complete before it completes itself. This is not a `Promise.all` feature. With this code `Promise.all([
    this.storage.remove(key1),`, ...]);` `this.storage.remove(key1)` is called and only the return value (a `Promise`) is added to the array that is passed to `Promise.all(...)`

Answer (score 38):

You could use `Observable.forkJoin` from `rxjs` by providing an array of all the `observables/promises`. This needs to be done before performing the operation. It's similar to Angular 1's `$q.all`.

## rxjs version <= 6

```ts
Observable.forkJoin([
   this.storage.remove(key1), 
   this.storage.remove(key2),
   this.storage.remove(key3)
])
.subscribe(t=> {
    var firstResult = t[0];
    var secondResult = t[1];
});
```

## rxjs version > 6

```ts
import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs';

forkJoin([
   this.storage.remove(key1), 
   this.storage.remove(key2),
   this.storage.remove(key3)
])
.subscribe(t=> {
    var firstResult = t[0];
    var secondResult = t[1];
});
```

Comment: Observable.forkJoin works for me. Rx.Observable.forkJoin does not.

Answer (score 5):

On `rxjs` version > 6 You can do something like this:

```
import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs';
```

and do instead of `Observable.forkJoin` this:

```
forkJoin([
  this.service1.get(),
  this.service2.get()
]).subscribe(data => {
  this.data1= data[0];
  this.data2 = data[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with IONIC, but assuming that storage.remove is returning a promise I would suggest you to use forkJoin operator from observables.

forkJoin takes an array of observables and awaits the execution of all items.

Just notice that I had to create 3 new observables from each promise returned by the .remove method.

```js
Observable.forkJoin([
   Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.remove(key1)), 
   Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.remove(key2)),
   Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.remove(key3))
])
.subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data[0]);
    console.log(data[1]);
    console.log(data[2]);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

> The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved, or rejects with the reason of the first passed promise that rejects.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> Promise.all(iterable);
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> iterable
>
> An iterable object, such as an Array. See iterable.

Answer (score 3):

use Promise.all for Promisses and Observable.forkJoin for Observables

as the question is about angular(2+) and you problably should have been using Observable instead of promises. i`ll add a GET example that worked for me:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
    
Observable.forkJoin(
      this._dataService.getOne().map(one => this.one = one),
      this._dataService.getTwo().map(two => this.two = two),
      this._dataService.getN().map(n => this.n = n),
     )
    ).subscribe(res => this.doSomethingElse(this.one, this.two, this.n));
```

note the use one .map() to handle the response rather than .subscribe()