# Angular 12: Wait for fetching all data (forkjoin) before proceeding

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

In my ngOnInit, I would like to wait for all requests of fetchLists to finish before proceeding:

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchLists();

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
         this.doSomethingWithFetchedLists();
      }
    });
  }

  fetchLists(): void {
    this.httpHandlerCached.getListsA()
      .subscribe(listA => this.listA = listA);
    this.httpHandlerCached.getListsB()
      .subscribe(listB => this.listB = listB);
    this.httpHandlerCached.getListsC()
      .subscribe(listC => this.listC = listC);
  }
```

Please hear me out, my previous question was closed with a reference to use "forkJoin": [Wait for multiple promises to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841721/wait-for-multiple-promises-to-finish)

However, with forkjoin I have the exact same issue:

```js
  fetchListnames() {
    return forkJoin([
      this.httpHandlerCached.getListsA(),
      this.httpHandlerCached.getListsB(),
      this.httpHandlerCached.getListsC(),
    ]).subscribe(res => {
        this.listA = res[0];
        this.listB = res[1];
        this.listC = res[2];
      });
  }
```

So with the proposal to use forkJoin, how can I now wait for the forkjoin to finish before proceeding (meaning before `this.doSomethingWithFetchedLists()` is called)?

Comment: Proceeding with what? Whatever you want to do with those results/response, you should be doing it in the subscribe block

Comment: Before this.doSomethingWithFetchedLists() is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's not recommended to put subscriptions inside of subscriptions as suggested by another answer. Instead, one should rely on rxjs pipes and subscribe just once.

In this case, one could think that putting `this.route.params` inside the `forkJoin` would do the trick, but because `this.route.params` will never complete, `forkJoin` won't emit (that's how `forkJoin` is implemented). To make `this.route.params` complete, you can pipe it into `take(1)`, resulting in this code:

```
forkJoin([
      this.httpHandlerCached.getListsA(),
      this.httpHandlerCached.getListsB(),
      this.httpHandlerCached.getListsC(),
      this.route.params.pipe(take(1))
    ]).subscribe(res => {
        this.listA = res[0];
        this.listB = res[1];
        this.listC = res[2];
        this.doSomethingWithFetchedLists();
      });
```

You can also use `combineLatest` instead of `forkJoin`, which instead of waiting for all observables to complete, will emit everytime one of the observables changes (but it will wait for all observables to emit at least one value first).

```
combineLatest([
          this.httpHandlerCached.getListsA(),
          this.httpHandlerCached.getListsB(),
          this.httpHandlerCached.getListsC(),
          this.route.params
        ]).subscribe(res => {
            this.listA = res[0];
            this.listB = res[1];
            this.listC = res[2];
            this.doSomethingWithFetchedLists();
          });
```

If you use the latter approach, you have to unsubscribe manually (or pipe to `take(1)`). Otherwise you will have memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Christian's answer, you can use `withLatestFrom` to avoid nested subscriptions

```
fetchListnames() {
    return forkJoin([
        this.httpHandlerCached.getListsA(),
        this.httpHandlerCached.getListsB(),
        this.httpHandlerCached.getListsC(),
    ])
    .pipe(
        withLatestFrom(this.route.params.pipe(take1)),
        map(([res, routeParams]) => {
            return { res, routeParams }    
        })
    )
    .subscribe(response => {
        let res = response.res;
        let routeParams = response.routeParams;
        this.listA = res[0];
        this.listB = res[1];
        this.listC = res[2];
        this.doSomethingWithFetchedLists();
        });
}
```